# Can a Dell PERC S110 software RAID be ignored under Linux?

Tags: dell-poweredge

I would like to use the Dell PowerEdge R520's on-board 6-port SATA controller which allows up to 4 SATA drives, however the configurator requires you to enable the S110 software RAID for that, which is Windows-only. Does that mean that Linux won't be able to see drives?

I want to use LVM so all that would require is that the drives are individually visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still interested in the Answer, [this here](http://paulsuela.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/windows-only-dell-poweredge-s100-s300-linux-software-raid/) should help you.

Summarized it means that you can disable the RAID functionality in the BIOS and create the Software Raid in Linux.
Windows only means that you don´t have to configure any RAID in Windows.